# Yii ajaxLink() only works once

Tags: php, ajax, listview, yii

I have a `CListView` that uses `ajaxLink()` in the `_view` file.

View (index.php)

```
<?php

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('ajaxUpdate',
"
//javascript function to update the listview using ajax
function updateItemList(){
    $.fn.yiiListView.update('itemList');
    return false;
}

", CClientScript::POS_READY);

?>
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'id'=>'itemList',

)); ?>
```

partial (_view.php)

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Delete',array('libdbitems/delete','id'=>$data->id),
                array('type'=>'POST','success'=>'function(){updateItemList()}'),
                array('confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                    'id'=>'delete-'.$data->id));  ?>
```

The controller is basically just the default `actionIndex()` that is generated with Gii.

Here's the problem: when I click my `Delete` link the first time after a page load, it behaves as expected. After that, clicking `Delete` does nothing. (It refreshes the ListView, but no changes are made.)

I'm pretty sure the problem lies in how Yii is binding `click()` events to my links in javascript, but I have no idea how to fix it. I have tried using the `live=true` option as others have suggested, but it does nothing.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue so that my Delete link works multiple times without having to reload the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh, a stupid fix. I realized I had accidentally left a `CHtml::$liveEvents = false` in my controller that I put there while I was still earlier in the troubleshooting phase.

The solution is just to leave `CHtml::$liveEvents = true` (default) and to make sure all the links have unique IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Is your delete link part of the itemlist that's refreshed?  If that's the case, the script won't re-register with the new link when a new link is created.

Two options:

1) Make sure your link is not being refreshed, and is a permanent aspect of the page

2) Write a custom jQuery handler rather than using Yii's ajaxLink.  You'll need to use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and delegated events.  Something of the form:

```
$("#parentContainer").on("click", ".deleteLinkClass', updateItemList)
```

Where the `parentContainer` is a permanent item on the page, and `deleteLinkClass` will be a class you'll need to assign to the delete links you're using.

Comment: Good suggestion, and it would have worked to write a custom handler. Luckily, I fixed a stupid mistake in my code. Voted you up anyway.